# Cursor is hand on non-clickable areas, and cursor on clickable areas

Tags: css, cursor

My react site is a bit too complicated to post all the code here, however I was wondering if anyone has had this issue and might have an idea of what is causing it.

For one of my pages the cursor states are flipped IE: on non-clickable areas it shows a hand, and in clickable areas it shows a cursor. It is also ONLY doing this on the mobile @media query version of the page.

I've tried to set cursor: default; in the wrapper of the page and that didn't do anything.

Thanks in advance to anyone that might be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I seem to have placed a cursor: property in the global scss file (no idea how that got there, or why it only affected the one page).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to provide the link to your website. ?

Comment: It's not live yet. I'm developing it locally.

Comment: You can add the property of those elements by hard coding them in your media query.

Comment: Which properties would those be?

Answer (score -1):

```
Cursor: default
```

and other cursor properties can be used.